# How to use TFS 2008 with Delphi 7 via MSBuild

Tags: delphi, tfs, msbuild, delphi-7

Has anyone had any luck using MSBuild with Delphi 7 as part of a TFS 2008 (Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2008) integration? Curious if it is possible, and if it is, what is necessary to set it up.

Thanks!

**Update**: I am aware that the later versions of Delphi use MSBuild, but it would appear for right now upgrading isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use MSBuild with Delphi 7, you must first produce a representative .dproj file bearing the correct XML markup (as seen in later versions of Delphi). If you construct them properly, then MSBuild will recognize them, and (as directed in the XML markup) will place the appropriate calls to the Delphi 7 compiler.
It's simple enough, but it takes a lot of effort to manually produce the .dproj markup!

**EDIT**: [This guy](http://tikotal.blogspot.com/2007/01/msbuild-for-delphi-task.html) offers an apparently-functional automated solution to this problem, available on request!

Comment: Can you point out any resources on creating the .dproj XML file?

Comment: Unfortunately not, as (to the best of my knowledge) I'm the only person who has actually done this. I can, however, assemble an example (and possibly even an automated tool to take a .DPR and produce an MSBuild D7 compiliant .DPROJ for you to use against MSBuild.

Comment: I'll let you know. BTW, congrats on your first Stack Overflow post.

Comment: Thanks! I've been meaning to peruse Stack Overflow to answer unresolved questions... just hardly have any time these days.

Answer (score 2):

You may write a MSBuild task that invokes dcc32.exe (delphi 7) and passes to it the appropriated commmand line (dpr file name). I wrote a similiar task for NANT in order to integrate delphi 7 with cc.net